# SQL Function and order by result?

Tags: sql, database, function, postgresql

I have this relation;
Country(name, code, capital, province, area, population)

from where I'd like to get the languages (name), the number of countries they are spoken in an the number of native speakers of each language.

I'm pretty sure I'm almost finished with this, but I don't think I've gotten the hang of what "ORDER BY" is really used for, because my calculation for count(l.name) gets messy and only gets me the values "1" when I know for certain that this database contains information where a certain language is spoken in several countries!

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.name, count(l.name) as SpokenIn, 
l.percentage*c.population as NativeSpeakers 
FROM (country c 
JOIN language l
ON c.code = l.country)
GROUP BY l.name, NativeSpeakers;
```

All other rows are fine, only the "SpokenIn" relation is messy. What am I doing wrong :(

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Well, first, you really don't need the DISTINCT qualifier as your group by clause specifies the field on which you want the counts to be based. You're getting "1" as the count because the DISTINCT ends up giving you one row for each result. Second, is that it looks like you're trying to do the percentage calculation *per country*, but trying to do a count against the whole language...

Comment: Does using a `SUM` instead of a `COUNT` work on `1.name`?

Comment: Where is the `ORDER BY` in this query, do you perhaps mean `GROUP BY`?

Comment: It can be most helpful to create an SQLFIDDLE so that answers can be easily verified.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select l.name,
       counter.num_countries as SpokenIn,
       sum(l.percentage * c.population) as NativeSpeakers
  from country c
  join language l
    on c.code = l.country
  join (select name, count(country) as num_countries
          from language
         group by name) counter
    on l.name = counter.name
 group by l.name, counter.num_countries
```

Edit - fixed spelling error "counties" vs. countries

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PostgreSQL expert but i think you made a litle grouping mistake. you are grouping over the NativeSpeakers column but you actually want the sum of all the nativespeakers. Try the following:

```
SELECT l.name, count(c.name) as SpokenIn, 
sum(l.percentage*c.population) as NativeSpeakers 
FROM (country c 
JOIN language l
ON c.code = l.country)
GROUP BY l.name;
```

if you want to fiddle some more with it:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d0bc/3

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to figure out how many people speak each language?  If so, this might be a better way to structure the query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT l.name, sum(l.percentage*c.population) as SpokenBy 
    FROM (country c 
    JOIN language l
    ON c.code = l.country)
    GROUP BY l.Name
```

Comment: Not really... I added the sum of all the nativespeakers. It might be that he wanted one line per country/language. Then your solution is more suitable to work from. It's not really clear what he is trying to do...